# C programming - Scanf/gets unexpected behaviour

Tags: c

The program is supposed to do the following:

### Add Major details

### Add University details

### Add major to university

### Update major cost

### Search for a major

Before completing the main function I'm facing a problem:

When I use scanf instead of gets in the functions, It asks 2 questions without letting me to fill the previous one. ex: Enter university's name: Enter university's address:
And when I used gets I faced the same problem.

If there's any other mistake please hint me

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Define Structures
typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    char department[30];
    int nb_students;
    int credits;
    float cost;
    char adv_name[15];
}Major;
typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    char address[30];
    Major uni_majors[50];
    int nb_majors;
}University;

// Define Functions Prototypes
Major majors_function();
University university_function();
void AddMajor(Major *major,University *university);
University UpdateMajor(char nameMajor[], University U, float newCost);
void SearchMajor(Major major,University university);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Major new_major;
    University new_university;

    new_major = majors_function();
    new_university = university_function();


    return 0;
}

// Fills The Major Details Function
Major majors_function() {

    Major major;

    printf("Enter Major name: ");
    gets(major.name);

    printf("Enter Department name: ");
    gets(major.department);

    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&major.nb_students);

    printf("Enter number of credits: ");
    scanf("%d",&major.credits);

    printf("Enter the cost of credit: ");
    scanf("%f",&major.cost);

    printf("Enter the Advisor's Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s",major.adv_name);

    return major;
}

// Fills the university details Function
University university_function() {
    University university;



    printf("Enter university's name: ");
    gets(university.name);

    printf("Enter university's address: ");
    gets(university.address);

    printf("Enter number of majors in this univeristy: ");
    scanf("%d",&university.nb_majors);


    return university;
}

// Adds Major to a university
void AddMajor(Major *major,University *university) {

    university->nb_majors = 0;
    if(university->nb_majors <50) {
        university->uni_majors[university->nb_majors] = *major;
    }
    else
        printf("No Available space");

    university->nb_majors++;


}

// Update Major's Cost
University UpdateMajor(char nameMajor[], University U, float newCost) {

    if(strcmp(nameMajor,U.uni_majors->name)) {
        U.uni_majors->cost = newCost;
    }
    return U;
}

// Searches for a major in a university
void SearchMajor(Major major,University university) {
    if(strcmp(university.uni_majors->name,major.name))
        printf("The total cost of this major is %.2f",(major.cost*major.credits));
    else
        printf("There is no such major!");
}
```

Comment: Read this about [scanf issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-mutliple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)

Answer (score 2):

When using `scanf` to scan strings or characters. you might want to skip leading whitespace (like newlines). This can simply be done by asking `scanf` to skip whitespace, by adding a single space in front of the format code, like

```
scanf(" %s",major.adv_name);
/*     ^      */
/*     |      */
/* Note space */
```

You might want to read more about `scanf` and its siblings on e.g. [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: wouldn't that cause a problem in the case of first input?

Comment: @sukhvir If there is no whitespace, then there's nothing to skip, so it won't skip anything. :)

Comment: `%s` will skip leading whitespace without the leading blank.  The only conversion specifiers that *don't* skip leading whitespace are `%c` and `%[`.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVERN NEVER NEVER** use `gets`, not for homework assignments, even for toy code.  It was deprecated in the 1999 standard and has been removed from the 2011 standard.  It *will* introduce a major point of failure in your program.  Use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets( major.name, sizeof major.name, stdin );
```

and check the return value to make sure it succeeded.

Alternately, you can use `scanf`, but you'll want to specify the max buffer size in the conversion specifier:

```
scanf( "%29s", major.name ); // leave 1 space for the 0 terminator
```

The only problem with this is that the size has to be hardcoded; you can't pass it as an argument like you do with `printf`.  Alternately, you can build the format string at runtime, like:

```
char fmt[5]; // good for %0s to %99s
sprintf( fmt, "%%%zus", sizeof major.name );
...
scanf( fmt, major.name );
```

Frankly, you're better off using `fgets` for everything, including the numeric inputs.

```
char inbuf[10];
char *chk;

// Read the number of students as text, then convert with the
// strtol library function; allows us to catch and reject
// non-numeric input. 
printf( "Enter number of students: " );
fflush( stdout );
if ( fgets( inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stdin ) != EOF )
{
  int tmp = (int) strtol( inbuf, &chk, 10 );
  if ( isspace( *chk ) || *chk == 0 )
  {
    major.nb_students = tmp;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid number\n", inbuf );
  }
}
```