# Input data in loop

Tags: c++, c

I want to input data by format "%d:%c"

I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    char letter;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        scanf("%c:%d", &letter, &number);
        printf("%c:%d\n", letter, number);
    }
}
```

I expect this:

```
Input: "a:1"
Output: "a:1"
Input: "b:2"
Output: "b:2"
Input: "c:3"
Output: "c:3"
```

But my program doing something like this:

```
a:1
a:1
b:2

:1
b:2

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you try to add `\n` in your `scanf` ?

Answer (score 6):

It's because when you read the input with `scanf`, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> character is still left in the buffer, so your next call to `scanf` will read it as the character.

This is easily solvable by telling `scanf` to skip whitespace, by adding a single space in the format code, like

```
scanf(" %c:%d", &letter, &number);
/*     ^                */
/*     |                */
/* Notice leading space */
```

Answer (score 0):

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-mutliple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s) might be helpful. using of %c after %d in scanf() function leads you in such difficulty.

Explaining in short, the '\n' you input after giving the number input of first test case will be taken as character input of second test case.

to avoid that you can edit your `scanf` statements as `scanf(" %c:%d",...);` . A leading space before %c avoids taking all those '\n' inputs as characters.

Answer (score 0):

OP says "... input data by format "%d:%c", yet code uses `"%c:%d"` and data input implies "char" then "number".

Suggest:

1) Determine the order desired.

2) Use a space before `"%c"` as in `" %c"` to consume leading whitespace like the previous line's <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or `'\n'`).