# C cannot read string after I read an integer

Tags: c, string

Below is my source code. After I read the integer, the program should wait until I type a string and then press enter. However, as soon as I enter the integer, the program exits. Can you tell me where is my fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int n;
    char command[255];

    scanf("%d", &n);
    fgets(command, 255, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

I mention that I also tried to use `gets(command)`, but I get the same result.

Comment: scanf doesn't consume the newline char ' \n' and fgets stops at that.

Comment: Also [fgets doesn't work after scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a trailing newline, since you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after the integer. Eat it by changing this:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%d ", &n); // this will eat trailing newline
```

As chux said, `scanf("%d ", &n)` will not return until the user enters the number and some following non-white-space.

---

Relevant question: [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)

Also I have in mind my example: [Caution when reading char with scanf](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/) .

Also, as Marco stated, you could use: `scanf("%d\n", &n);`, which targets the newline specifically.

---

There is also this possibility:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int n;
    char command[255], newline;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%c", &newline); // eat trailing newline
    fgets(command, 255, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

---

However, I would personally use two `fgets()` and no `scanf()`. :)

Comment: Why not `scanf("%d\n", &n);`? Looks clearer.

Comment: That would work too @MarcoBonelli, grazie.

Comment: `scanf("%d ", &n);` will not return until the user enters the number and some following non-white-space.

Comment: That's true @chux, I am updated the answer, if you think we can improve it further, please let me know.

Comment: For learner code, now it is fine. The basic issue with `scanf("%d ", &n)` is with many SO posts where that trailing `" "` causes issues.  In the end, `scanf()` is the weak link and certainly problematic to mix with `fgets()`. I would have used 2 `fgets()` calls - but the issues that it helps are likely well  beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: @chux I agree with your last statement and that's how I was taught, so please allow me to update.

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf()` leaves newline character after the integer, and `fgets()` will read it and exit.

Try reading all input with `fgets()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char buffer[255];
    int n;
    char command[255];

    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
    fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! - Good to not mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`  (Best to not use `scanf()` as this answer did not).

Answer (score 1):

Typing `"3c"` and pressing enter in your console will make your input buffer `stdin` look like this: `{'3','c','\n'}` and would work, since scanf consumes the 3, fgets consumes the `c`, and the `\n` would be where `fgets` stops.

But if you type "3" and press enter, scanf will consume the 3, and the newline character will be left, causing fgets to consume no characters.

Comment: The input buffer would be `{'3', 'c', '\n'}` in the first scenario, right? I think you accidentally typed 'd' instead of 'c' ?

Comment: @Polb yah, sorry about that