# scanf not working as expected

Tags: c, scanf

I tried to execute the following simple code in ubuntu 15.10 But the code behaves odd than expected

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n,i=0;
char val;
char a[20];

printf("\nEnter the value : ");
scanf("%s",a);
printf("\nEnter the value to be searched : ");
scanf("%c",&val);

int count=0;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
 if(a[i]==val){
   printf("\n%c found at location %d",val,i);
   count++;
 }
}
printf("\nTotal occurance of %c is %d",val,count);
   return 0;
}

output:
--------------------------
Enter the value : 12345678
Enter the value to be searched : 
Total occurance of is 0
```

The second scanf to get the value to be searched seems not to be working. The rest of the code executes after the first scanf without getting input second time.

Comment: 1) `scanf("%c",&val);` --> `scanf(" %c",&val);` 2) `i<20` --> `i<20 && a[i]` 3) `scanf("%s",a);` --> `scanf("%19s", a);` (`i<20` --> `ia[i]`)

Comment: `ia[i]` my typo as `a[i]`

Comment: Why not check the return value from `scanf`? Also get it to not overrun the array

Comment: If you're on SO howling in anguish about it, scanf() is working precisely as expected.

Comment: %c accept '\n', 12345678(Enter) -> 12345678'\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first scanf(), in every scanf(), in formatting part, put a whitespace

So change this

```
scanf("%c",&val);
```

into this

```
scanf(" %c",&val);
```

Reason is, scanf() returns when it sees a newline, and when first scanf() runs, you type input and hit enter. scanf() consumes your input but not remaining newline, so, following scanf() consumes this remaining newline.

Putting a whitespace in formatting part makes that remaining newline consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, i = 0;
    char val;
    char a[20];

    printf("\nEnter the value : ");
    fgets(a, 20, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter the value to be searched : ");
    scanf("%c", &val);

    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (a[i] == val) {
            printf("\n%c found at location %d", val, i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nTotal occurance of %c is %d", val, count);
    return 0;
}
```

or clear `stdin`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void clearstdin(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}

int main() {
    int n, i = 0;
    char val;
    char a[20];

    printf("\nEnter the value : ");
    scanf("%s",a);
    clearstdin();
    printf("\nEnter the value to be searched : ");
    scanf("%c", &val);

    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (a[i] == val) {
            printf("\n%c found at location %d", val, i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nTotal occurance of %c is %d", val, count);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, see [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\nEnter the value : ");
scanf("%s",a);
printf("\nEnter the value to be searched : ");
scanf("%d",&val);   // here is different
```

i don't know why, but code above working...

```
scanf("%d",&val);
```

Comment: `scanf` clears whitespace except when the character format (`%c`) is used. In OP's example typing `12345678` and pressing enter means that `a` gets `12345678` and there is a newline (`'\n'`) character in the stdin buffer. `%d` removes it but `%c` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use " %c" instead of "%c" for the format string. The blank causes scanf() to skip white space (including newlines) before reading the character.