# scanf() function with different format specifier

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

Below is a program which accepts two character and prints them

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c1, c2;
    printf("\n Enter characters one : ");
    scanf(" %c", &c1);
    printf("\n Enter character two : ");
    scanf("%c", &c2);
    printf("\n The the characters are %c and %c ", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Now one output instance is :-

```
Enter two characters : a
The the characters are a and
```

The problem is that I haven't given any space between two format specifier `%c`
Here I pressed 'a' and then '\n' which gets stored into c1 and c2 respectively. And thus I got output which was not accepted.

I know how to correct this problem.

Now I make the same program for the integers :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("\n Enter two numbers : ");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("\n The two numbers are %d and %d ", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Here we will not found any problem.

I think this time we didn't encounter problem because the second input we give is `'\n'` or space which is not any integer and thus we get a failure in the reading from the `scanf()` function so the input buffer is still active and if we press the next input as integer then it gets stored into variable `'b'`.

Can you tell me the reason which I thought is correct or not?

Now if it is correct then what will happen if I press again a character. Then also it should not get stored into the variable `'b'` but this time 0 gets stored into variable `'b'`.

So my question is that what is the reason for proper behavior of the program when I'm trying to make the same program with `%d`

Comment: `scanf("%c", &c2);` --> `scanf(" %c", &c2);` with the space just like the first usage. The `%d` format skips whitespace, the `%c` format does not. The `space` makes it do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)

Comment: no it's not... I have gone through that and after that i asked this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, let's have a look at `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.

So, when you have a `newline` (`'\n'`, which is indeed a white-space character) left in the input buffer,

- in case of `scanf("%c", &charVar);`, the newline is considered as the input, so the second scanf *skips* asking for the input from user.
- in the case of `scanf("%d", &intVar);` the leftover `newline` is *skipped* and it wait for the *integer* input to appear, so it *stops and asks* the user for the input.

However, FWIW, in later case, if you input a non-whitespace *character* and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the *char* input will be considered as an *input*, causing a matching failure.

Related

> [...] If
>   the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this
>   condition is a matching failure.

Comment: from where do you get to see `C11 standard, chapter §7.21.6.2`?

Comment: @rajaTHEKING Sorry I did not get you. What do you mean _from where_? It is in the standard document. I've N1570. Which one you're referring to? Based on the revision, chapter numbering maybe slightly different.

Comment: @raja THE KING 2  I googled "Input white-space characters (as specified by" and came up with many hits including [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Input-Conversions.html)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was just asking for the link of that `C11 standard`. So that I can use that to refer many other things. Anyways thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @rajaTHEKING I see. Actual standard document costs money because you've to buy it, however the draft versions are pretty good, too. You can find an [online version](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

It's reading the new line as the newline is a character. Simply changing `scanf("%c", &c2);` to `scanf(" %c", &c2);` will make it work.

So in your code:
    #include

```
int main()
{
    char c1, c2;
    printf("\n Enter characters one : ");
    scanf(" %c", &c1);
    printf("\n Enter character two : ");
    scanf(" %c", &c2);
    printf("\n The the characters are %c and %c ", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already know how to make that work, but I want to know that what difference is being created when I'm using %d format specifier. And specially the reason for it.

Comment: @rajaTHEKING The new line cannot be parsed as an int which makes the diffrence in this case.

Comment: okay, I think that the new line can't be parsed into int because its a character ('\n') .. right?

Comment: And if this is the reason then all the next inputs which are character should also not be parsed as the int.

Comment: @rajaTHEKING It looks for the number character (0-9) and views the newline character as a separator between the two formatting flags as it also would  a space. If you decided you wanted to use the character 'q' to separate the two numbers you would get like in this  string `1q2`, you would get 1 and 0 as an answer because it comes to a character that is not a number or a separator and thus is junk so it just gives you 0 back because what you tried to put in the formatting flag doesn't make sense..