# scanf function skips values in while loop for scanning character value

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,t;
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%s",&c);
        printf("%c",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

inside the while loop why it skips some of values. but it works okay with integer values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy it is not the same. this is UB.

Comment: *"inside the while loop why it skips some of values"* What values does it skip? Is there some kind of pattern? Can you describe the problem in more detail? Perhaps by giving sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: i guess it reads the new line character '\n' when enter is pressed. that is the problem..

Answer (score 2):

`%s` is used to scan strings (not `char`'s), change to `%c`

Comment: actuly it is %c instead of %s. but still. using %c it skips a value.

Comment: @RishiSahu as well as correcting the format spec, put a space in front, as `scanf(" %c",&c);` then it will skip whitespace. `%d` and `%s` do automatically, but `%c` does not, without that little space.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c) could be a solution. use:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

instead of:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```