# Linked List element insertion at nth location

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to implement linked list in C and I have two different functions that are supposed to insert elements in the beginning and at nth position. My program crashes when it goes to the part where it starts executing the function to insert at nth position. Can someone please point out my mistake. Also the compiler tends to skip the last scanf statement (marked in the comments).

```
/****************************************************************
*Date: 12/30/2016
*This program adds an element to the beginning  and nth position
*of a linked list and then displays the elements in the list
*****************************************************************/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>



struct node
{
    int data;//Refers to the data part of the linked list
    struct node* next;//Refers to the pointer which points to the next element
};


/*************************************************************************************
Description   : This function is used to print the elements in the linked list
Input         : Pointer to the beginning of the linked list
Output        : N/A
*************************************************************************************/


void PrintElements(struct node *start)
{
    if(start==NULL)//If the list is empty
        printf("List is empty");
    else
    {
        while(start!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ",start->data);
            start=start->next;
        }
    }
}

/*************************************************************************************
Description   : This function is used to insert elements in the beginning of the
                linked list
Input         : Element to be inserted
Output        : N/A
*************************************************************************************/

struct node* InsertElementInTheBeginning(struct node *start, int x)
{
    struct node *new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(new_node==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return start;
    }
    new_node->data=x;
    new_node->next=start;
    start=new_node;
    return new_node;

}

/*************************************************************************************
Description   : This function is used to insert elements in the nth position of the
                linked list
Input         : Element and position to be inserted, pointer to beginning of linked
                list
Output        : N/A
*************************************************************************************/

struct node* InsertElementAtN(struct node *start,int x, int n)//Here the starting position for the linked list is assumed to be 1
{
    int i;
    struct node* new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(new_node==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return start;
    }
    new_node->data=x;
    new_node->next=NULL;
    if(n==1)
    {
        new_node->next=start;
        start=new_node;
        return start;
    }
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=start;
    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    new_node->next=ptr->next;
    ptr->next=new_node;
    return start;
}

int main()
{

    int x, n;
    struct node *HEAD;
    struct node *ptr;
    HEAD=NULL; //Assigning HEAD to null when there are no elements in the list
    ptr=NULL;
    printf("\n\rEnter numbers to be inserted into the list\n Press q to quit\n");
    while(scanf("%d",&x)==1)
    {
        HEAD=InsertElementInTheBeginning(HEAD,x);
        PrintElements(HEAD);
        printf("\n\rEnter numbers to be inserted into the list\n Press q to quit\n");
    }
        printf("\n\rEnter the number and position to be inserted");
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&n);//The compiler always skips this scanf no clue why
        HEAD=InsertElementAtN(HEAD, x, n);
        PrintElements(HEAD);

     //Freeing dynamic memory

    while(HEAD!=NULL)
    {
        ptr=HEAD;
        HEAD=ptr->next;
        free(ptr);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _skip the last scanf statement_ because _Press q to quit_ It is necessary to remove the entered `q`.

Comment: try `scanf("q%d %d",&x,&n);` or `scanf("%*[Qq]%d %d",&x,&n);`

Comment: Who on earth taught you to put `\n\r` at the **beginning** of the message?!

Comment: Consider never using `scanf()`.  Use `fgets()` to read user input instead and then process the string into `int`, etc.

Comment: If you must use `scanf()`, always check the function return value.  Code did that with `while(scanf("%d",&x)==1)` - good.  Curiously code did not with `scanf("%d %d",&x,&n);` and that is where a problem lies.

Comment: My first guess is you need to change `"%d %d"` to `" %d %d"` to ignore the `\n` at the end of the last line. If you're having trouble reading integers with `scanf`, it's very possible that the problem is a non-integer value in the input stream, and the space before `%d` will ignore any space characters at least. Checking the return value of `scanf` as chux suggested is still a very good idea :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a getchar() after the first while loop in the main(). For explanation please check [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s).

Answer (score 1):

I've always found something like this to be easier for me to understand (I'm assuming your positions must be 1 or more based on your code, unlike the usual C convention of 0 or more):

```
struct node *insertValueAt(struct node *head, int value, int position) {
    struct node *current;

    if (head == NULL || position == 1)
         return insertBefore(head, value);

    for (current = head; position > 1 && current->next != NULL; position--)
        current = current->next;

    current->next = insertBefore(current->next, value);

    return head;
}
```

Note that I used the name `insertBefore`, but your `InsertElementAtTheBeginning` does the same thing. The key to inserting a node `N` between to existing nodes `A` and `B` is to make `A->next` point to `N` that is returned from `InsertElementAtTheBeginning(B, value)`.

Another thing to note is the unconditional insertion before a `NULL` node (i.e. at the beginning of an empty list or at the end of the list), regardless of the value of `position` because you can't insert an item at position 10 if you only have fewer than 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

you should check that ptr->next is not NULL.

```
 for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
 {
    if (ptr->next == NULL) return NULL;
    ptr=ptr->next;
 }
```

Comment: I did try making that change but it still skips the scanf statements that I have marked in the comments. Even using getchar instead of scanf does not make a difference.