# fscanf won't work twice?

Tags: c

I'm just trying to get fscanf to read all the characters in a file, along with all the words, but whenever I try to run a `while`loop on the file I opened twice it doesn't seem to work? It only seems to be able to use `fscanf`on a file **one time**. I found a work around where I can scan the same file twice except I need to open the file a **2nd time** for this to work. How can I use `fscanf` on the same instance of a file twice?

```
/*Description: Program will open a file named Story.txt
           then counts the number of words and characters
           and prints them out */

int main(){

char word[225]; // will be used to hold words (array of chars)
char c; // will be used to hold chars
int wordCount = 0; // will be used to hold the number of words in the file
int charCount = 0; // will be used to hold the number of chars in the file

FILE* wordFile = fopen("Story.txt","r"); // opens the file Story.txt for counting words

printf("Words: "); // indicates that the following outout will be the words of the file

while(fscanf(wordFile,"%s",&word)==1){ // a loop to scan the file for all the words in it until the end of the file
    printf(" %s ",word); // prints out the word in the given cycle
    wordCount = wordCount + 1; // keeps count of the words the loop has scanned up till now
}

fclose(wordFile); // closes wordFile and frees the memory
FILE* charFile = fopen("Story.txt","r"); // opens file Story.txt for counting chars

printf("\n\nChars: "); // indicates the following output will be the chars of the file

while(fscanf(charFile,"%c",&c)==1){ // a loop to scan the file for all the chars in it until the end fot he file
    if(c!=' '){ // will check if the char is a space, if it is it will not count it
        printf(" %c ",c); // prints out the char for the given cycle
        charCount = charCount + 1; // keeps count of the chars the loop has scanned up till now
    }
}

fclose(charFile); // closes charFile and frees the memory

printf("\n\nWord count: %d and Char count: %d",wordCount,charCount-1); // prints out the word count and char count

return 0;
}
```

As you can see i have to create **two** instances of the file or else it will not work. The first instance is called `wordFile` and the 2nd instance is called `charFile`. Here's the thing though: **Both loops work**, it's just that I can't use them on the same file **twice**. How can I make it so that I will only need to open **one** instance of the file and then use it to count both the words and the chars in it?

Things I tried: adding the space as suggested here didn't work: [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s) (i searched fscanf but scanf is all that came up so i went off of that).

Another work around that I found strange: if i use `wordFile`in the 2nd while loop to search for chars it works, the only problem is I have to declare `fclose(wordFile);` **right before** it's used in the `while` loop. I thought `fclose`was suppose to close the file and make it unusable? Anyways that worked but what I really want is to use use **one instance of the file** to read all the chars and strings in it.

Comment: C != C++. If this is C++, you should use C++ constructs and don't tag C, if this is C, don't tag C++.

Comment: If that is what you want, you can read the string and chars at the same time. Read char by char, when you encounter a space, start a new word but continue adding it to the chars. But really in your program you aren't reading the chars in, but reading the char and outputting it...

Comment: `rewind(wordFile);` between passes?

Comment: It's safer for you to set the buffer size in the `fscanf` format argument. 225 chars should be big enough, but it's still better to be safe than sorry: `fscanf(wordFile, "%224s", &word)`

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is.  Once you `fscanf` your pointer is moved.  In your 1st loop after, your word count, do a `strlen` to get the charCount.

Comment: I know there's other ways of doing this but I **need** to do it this way. I need to use a loop to get the strings and a loop to get the chars and in those loop I need to print them out. I just want to understand why I can't use the same file twice to do this. I can't use anything else but what I already have in my code. Thanks for the suggestions though, again not trying to get you guys to do this for me I'm just asking one thing: How can I use the same file twice in both loops?

Comment: What is the longest word in "Story.txt"?

Comment: `fclose(wordFile); 
FILE* charFile = fopen("Story.txt","r");` --> `rewind(wordFile);`

Comment: @chux I can only use what's already in my code sorry so I wouldn't be able to use 'rewind', thank you for your answer though. Also, the longest word in "Story.txt" is "Something"

Comment: you can eliminate the extra open/close calls and the second FILE* variable by calling `fseek( wordFile, 0, SEEK_SET );` or `rewind( wordFile );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like below - the lazy way of course

```
char word[225]; 
char c; 
int wordCount = 0; 
int charCount = 0; 

FILE* wordFile = fopen("Story.txt","r"); 

printf("Words: "); 

while(fscanf(wordFile,"%s",word)==1){  // word gives the address not &word
    wordCount = wordCount + 1; 
}

printf("%d\n",wordCount);

fseek(wordFile,0,SEEK_SET); // setting the file pointer to point to the beginning of file

printf("Chars: "); 

while(fscanf(wordFile,"%c",&c)==1){ 
    if(c!=' '&& c!='\n' && c!='\t'){ 
        charCount = charCount + 1; 
    }
}
printf("%d\n",charCount);
fclose(wordFile);  // Closing the file once for all

return 0;
```

Comment: thank you I understand now, but why do I need to set it to the beginning of the file? Is this just how 'fscanf' works, so every time I want to scan the entire file I need to set it back to the beginning?

Comment: `so every time I want to scan the entire file I need to set it back to the beginning? ` - YES ! But this is a very lazy approach as I already mentioned. A better option would be count the number of characters in each string, isn't it?

Comment: @user7839375, it has nothing to do with `fscan()` but rather the concept of the `current file pointer`  which indicates the location in the file where a read or write operation will be preformed.  each call to `fscan()` advances that 'current file pointer` through the file by the number of bytes read.  So after the first loop is completed, the `current file pointer` will indicate the end of the file.  a call to `rewind()` or `fseek( wordFile, 0, SEEK_SET);` will move the `current file pointer` back to the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(wordFile,"%s",&word);
```

The variable "word" is the pointer to the first element of your array (string), so here you are scanning the address not the value. You should rather use:

```
fscanf(wordFile,"%s",word);
```