# How to scan two or more strings containing spaces in C programming?

Tags: c

I'm trying to run this code, but it is not working.Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code
After receiving the first input the program is terminating.

```
int main()
{
    char   name[100],college_name[100],address[100];
    printf("Enter your name :");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
    printf("Enter college name :");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",college_name);
    printf("Enter address :");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",address);
}
```

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` --> `"%99[^\n]%*c"`

Comment: Flushing the input stream helped me several times.

Comment: flushing the input stream is undefined behaviour...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)

Comment: Change `scanf("%[^\n]s",name); `to `scanf("%s",name);`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre through `fflush()`. A homegrown API _eating up_ the remaining input may work just fine, though. :)

Comment: @BetaRunner-- the goal of `%[^\n]` is to read strings including spaces.

Comment: in that case, `fgets` is just as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scanf` calls are correctly reading everything up to — but *not* including — the `\n`.

The problem is that the `\n` remains on the input stream.  So when the second and third `scanf` calls run, they find nothing.  (They read zero characters up to but not including the next `\n`.)

The simplest fix would be to call `getchar()` to read and discard the `\n` characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100],college_name[100],address[100];
    printf("Enter your name :");
    scanf("%[^\n]",name);
    getchar();       /* discard \n */
    printf("Enter college name :");
    scanf("%[^\n]",college_name);
    getchar();       /* discard \n */
    printf("Enter address :");
    scanf("%[^\n]",address);
    getchar();       /* discard \n */
}
```

(I've also removed the extraneous `s` characters from the `scanf` calls.  It's `%[…]`, not `%[…]s`.)

Now, at one level this is a poor fix.  Theoretically, we should check that the character read by `getchar()` was actually a `\n`.  But (a) in this case it pretty much has to be, and (b) any program that uses `scanf` to read user input is already kludgey and unreliable, so adding some kludgey and potentially unreliable (but simple) `getchar` calls won't make it any worse.

(Some people will suggest -- one comment even suggested -- calling `fflush(stdin)` to get rid of the extraneous newlines.  That might work on some platforms, but it's not guaranteed to and it won't work everywhere, so it's an even worse fix.)

The real lesson here is, don't use `scanf` for user input like this.  It is, unfortunately, the obvious first choice for user input in beginning programs like this, because it *seems* so easy and convenient.  But it turns out (when you try to make programs that actually work) `scanf` is actually just about impossibly *in*convenient, so as soon as you've learned a little more about C, you'll want to abandon `scanf` entirely, and do all your input using more robust, reliable techniques.  (Your next question is likely to be, more reliable techniques like what?  One is to read lines of user input using `fgets()`, then manipulate those lines as necessary.  See also http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html, [https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html), and [https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx12e.html.](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx12e.html.))

---

Addendum: I said, "The simplest fix would be to call `getchar()` to read and discard the `\n` characters."  But there's an even simpler fix: change the second and third `scanf` calls (or all three of them, for consistency) to

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",address);
```

Notice the innocent-looking extra space.  In any `scanf` call, a space in the format string means "read and discard whitespace characters".  So on the second and third calls, that will take care of the `\n` that's leftover from the first and second calls.

Most `scanf` format specifiers (the ones like `%d` and `%s` and `%f`) skip leading whitespace automatically.  But a few of them — notably `%c` and `%[…]` — do not.  So for those, you typically want to include  space character in the format string to cause the leftover `\n` from the preceding call to be skipped.

Comment: Also the `s` does not make sense here. `%[^\n]` already asks for all characters but a new-line.

Comment: @alk Ah, right.  I almost always miss that (in part because, following my own advice, I never use `scanf`).  Answer edited.