# Can't understand function output (C)

Tags: c, function

trying to learn C i got stuck with this: I'm trying to write a function squared which should print on screen a filled square with  size and filling character choosen by the user. So i wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int squared (int side, char fillCharacter);

int main(){
    int side;
    char fillCharacter;

    printf("Enter the side ");
    scanf("%d", &side);

    printf("Enter the character ");
    scanf("%c", &fillCharacter);

    printf("%d%c",squared(side, fillCharacter));
}

int squared (int side, char fillCharacter){
    for (int row=1 ; row <=  side; row++){
        for (int i =1; i <= side; i++){
        printf("%c", fillCharacter);

        }
    puts("");

    }
}
```

But sadly the output of this doesn't even scan for the character and just print a blank space

```
Enter the side 2
Enter the character
```

I tried change things but i made it worse so if someone could give me a hint i really would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything and you put a call of it inside a printf which is expecting an int and a char.

Comment: please try this: `scanf( " %c", &fillCharacter );`  (put a space before %c)

Comment: To enter an integer, you type a value (say `2`), and then hit the enter key.   `%c` picks up that enter key as a character (and it is a whitespace character).

Comment: Stop using `scanf()`. The user expects their input to take effect when they hit <enter>, one line at a time. That's also what the terminal does in effect. So do the same, and read full lines with `fgets()` or `getline()` (you can then `sscanf()` those). http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush1.html

Comment: @ikkachu thank you for your explanation, i'm just using scanf() because it's on the book i'm reading in order to learn C; i'm halfway so maybe they will introduce fgets() etc later. But thanks.

Comment: @Peter thank you so much now i got it why it "didn't even take the second entry".

Comment: @MikeNakis you are right , it works but can you explain me why please, i mean maybe i get it but just to be sure it's better if you tell me.

Comment: The two questions of which this is a duplicate have answers that explain fairly well what's happening and why this fixes it.

Comment: @Bob__ Well i tried with adding return by: return for (int row=1 ; row <=  side; row++){
   for (int i =1; i <= side; i++){
   printf("%c", fillCharacter);but it just "returned" this: error: expected expression before ‘for’
   return for (int row=1 ; row <=  side; row++){
          ^

Comment: You missed the point. Either your function [returns nothing](https://ideone.com/EhEAuc) or it [returns a meaningful value](https://ideone.com/ZXnNvv). `for` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Bob__  very helpful thank you, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is linked to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562355/4949918). This answer provides a fix but you could just fix it by reversing the calls to scanf: first the character and then the number.