# Why scanf() function is not wait me for entring char at the last in below code

Tags: c

I am trying to getting an value in variable c which has an data type of character but it not ask me or wait me to enter the character

I have used   fflush(stdin);  this to flushing previous value if any but it wont work for me

```
int main()
{
int a =10;
float f;
double d;
char c ;

scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%d \n",a);

scanf("%f",&f);
printf("%f \n",f);

scanf("%lf",&d);
printf("%lf \n",d);

fflush(stdin);

scanf("%c",&c);
printf("%c \n",c);
return 0;
}
```

Here is what my output looks like

[image]

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is questionable: [SO: what is the use of fflush(stdin) in c programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/7478597).

Comment: `fflush()` has undefined behaviour for input streams.  `stdin` is an input stream.

Comment: Though this might compile in C++ as well, to me, it looks like a C question. Please, prevent tag spamming (and [edit] your question to remove one of the tags).

Comment: I'm guessing the `scanf("%c")` is reading a lingering unread line break char from the previous `scanf("%lf")`. In C++, this is easy to deal with using `std::cin.ignore()`. In C, you can use `getline()` and discard what is read

Comment: This seems a good reading concerning your issue: [SO: How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/7478597).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left over `\n` from the `scanf("%lf",&d);` will be consumed at `scanf("%c",&c);`.
Hence the double line feed in the output.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562835/1413395) from the marked duplicate seems to provide a good workaround for the problem (emphasis mine):

> ```
> scanf(" %c",&c);
>     // ^
> ```
>
> You can probably rescue it by using `" %c"` instead of `"%c"` for the format string. The blank causes `scanf()` to **skip white space (including newlines)** before reading the character.

Comment: thanks it work for me for adding extra blank space