# Can anybody know how to deal with this?

Tags: c

I'm new on programming and I have started learning C language by my own. Although there is an issue on the following screenshot that I am not able to understand its logic. Specifically I don't know why C skips the part of `scanf` in the called function. Does the order of calling matter? Thank you very much.

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7XTg.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
void GiveLetter(); // function prototype #1
void GiveNumber(); // function prototype #2
int main ()
{
    int x;
    printf("Give me the first number:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Your first number is: %d\n",x);
    printf("Hello Panos\n");
    GiveLetter();
    GiveNumber();
    return 0;

}
void  GiveLetter()
{
    char Letter;
    printf("Give a letter:\n");
    scanf("%c",&Letter);
    printf("Your letter is %c\n",Letter);
}
void GiveNumber()
{
    int Number;

    printf("Give the second number:");
    scanf("%d",&Number);
    printf("Your second number is %d\n",Number);
}
```

Comment: Post real (copy/paste) code, not (bad resolution) images.

Comment: You `scanf("%d",..` which asks for a _number_, not a _letter_. Use `"%c"` for a singe letter. And paste the code here, not an image.

Comment: but i have used "%c".sorry for the image as i said i am new and i dont know to to paste the code here (it doesnt allow me).

Comment: please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562355/2331445

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You scanf a number in main(). That leaves the ENTER in the input buffer which is read by the scanf inside the function.

Ask scanf to ignore whitespace (unlike `"%c"`, `"%d"` already ignores whitespace on its own)

```
scanf(" %c", ...);
//     ^ ignore whitespace
```

Better yet. Use **only** `fgets()` for user input. It's a safe alternative, with good error reporting and recovery.

Comment: The problem appears when i call the  function "GiveLetter".I tried to call it before the variable definition in the main and it worked.i dont know why.

Comment: @NavyAlsk, It worked because the input buffer is empty when you call the function before the ```int x```, If you call the function ```GiveLetter()``` after ```scanf("%d",&x);``` statement, then input buffer contains the  ```ENTER``` character, so in the next scanf statement the ```ENTER``` character is read as next input, and it seems to the user as if the ```scanf()``` has been skipped by the program, to avoid this case follow the above answer by @pmg

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you.You have helped me so much.I apologize for asking too much but as i said i have just started learning ! :)