# Why can I only enter the name and not the others?

Tags: c

```
if (choice=1){
    printf("Enter the name of the patient:\n");
    scanf("%d", name);
    printf("Enter the date of birth of the patient:\n");
    scanf("%s", birthmonth, birthday, birthyear);
    printf("Enter the gender of the patient:\n");
    scanf("%s", gender);
    printf("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
    getch();
            
}
```

Whenever I run this part of my code, it only allows me to enter the name of the patient. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are you trying to enter a full name, with a space between the first and the last name? Also, is this C++ or C code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s

Comment: Additionally to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789) you are telling scanf to read one number as patient name. So as long as you don't enter a number, it won't advance. I guess you wanted `%s` instead of `%d`. Plus, a long name could then crash your program, so you should limit the length to the size of your string, for example `%20s`. But then you'll have another issue with the birthdate, there you are reading one string but specifying three variables. If your variables are integers, you likely want something like `scanf("%d/%d/%d", &birthmonth, &birthday, &birthyear)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an integer placeholder (`%d`) instead of (`%s`) for a string in the first `scanf` statement.

And in the second `scanf` statement, you should be using 3x `%s`, to get input to the three variables.

Comment: `%d` is integer - `%e`/`%f` would be double.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.