# I writing code to make marksheet of 10th class. there is fourth scanf is not taking input

Tags: c, input, scanf

My fourth scanf is not taking input?

I'm trying to make mark sheet in c language. Then my first three `scanf` run properly but my fourth `scanf` is not taking input my program is directly stop executing.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int subject, mathematics, english, hindi, science, socialScience;
    char school[50];
    char name[50];
    char section[5];
    int standard;
    int total;

    printf("\nPlease Enter your school name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", school);

    printf("\nEnter student name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);

    printf("\nenter standard: ");
    scanf("%d", &standard);

    printf("\nenter your section:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", section);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: The general advice around here when it comes to `scanf` is: Forget that it exists. Use `fgets` to read lines, and then possibly `sscanf` to parse the lines.

Comment: Side note: If you use `scanf` or `sscanf` etc., you should always check return value. Also, if you don't have a `\n` at the end of your output, you might not see it due to line buffering of `stdout`. If you don't want `\n` because you want to get the input in same line, you can use `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf` calls.

Comment: Instead of trying to kludge away the newline with `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", school);` you must filter out any *leading* newline with `scanf(" %[^\n]", school);` with an added space. This is how the function is intended to be used. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: `scanf("%d", &standard);` - ask yourself what is left in the input stream immediately *after* that happens. Consider every keystroke you hit; *every single keystroke*. What did you hit after you finished the last digit of `standard` ? Now, what causes the next `scanf` to *stop* parsing its first argument?

Comment: You must also restrict the input length, escpecially with a tiny buffer like `char section[5];` with `scanf(" %4[^\n]", section);`

Comment: Begin again. You've already instantiated lots of variables when you encounter a problem. "Incremental Development"... As others have said, shun `scanf()` and use `fgets()` to load into a general purpose buffer that you can `strncpy()`. Get one field working before moving on to the next. Use `val = atoi(buffer)` instead of `scanf("%d")...

Answer (score 0):

Add a getchar() after the 3rd scanf(). But as other have suggested, please move to fgets().[Check this answer for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)